# Is it possible to push and receive Notification to another clone application with same source code

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

Hi i had published an school app and the system is designed to push the `Notification` with several school id. User which input school email as registered in database. The User received push `Notification` according to the school id. All is working fine on this app.

But i am going to clone the app with just different school logo and different school images. Is it possible for me to clone the source codes and receive the notification as expected ?

Would be appreciated if any advise is given, thanks !

Comment: as long as your **app package name, API KEY, SHA KEY** are same they will work

Comment: noted with thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes with same **app package name, API KEY, SHA KEY** then it will work